# How can I create overlapping, transparent bars in a D3 bar chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to create a chart like this example:
[Population pyramid](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062085)

But without the sliding; no need to adjust year or anything. This is roughly the dataset I have:

```
category,subcategory,benchmark,completes,difference
household income,"Less than $30,000",33.7,27.4,6.3
household income,"$30,000 to $74,000",31.6,36.3,4.7
household income,"$75,000 to $124,999",20.3,22.4,2.1
household income,"$125,000 Plus",14.2,13.9,0.3
```

I want to have a transparent bar for the benchmark, and a transparent bar for the completes (so that the disparity between them can be seen)

Where I have problems is putting two rects in each 'g' container

```
// G containers for subcategory bars
    subcat = svg.selectAll('.subcat')
        .data(data)
        .enter().append('g')
        .attr('class','subcat')
        .attr('transform', function(d) {
            return 'translate(' + x(d.subcategory) + ', 0)';
        });

    subcat.selectAll('.bar')
        .data(data)
        .enter().append('rect')
        .attr('class','bar')
        .attr('width', x.rangeBand())
        .attr('y', function(d) { return y(d.benchmark); })
        .attr('height', function(d) { return height - y(d.benchmark); });
```

I don't have a very good understanding of the data() method of a selection, hence my problem. I have read about keys, entries and rollups and I think that might be a possible place to look for a solution.

Most of the D3 examples I have worked with use one piece of data for each column, so the data binding makes sense. In this case, I want to put two bars in each column so the data binding process is unclear to me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure I completely understand what you want. if you just want to visualize overlapping bars, one based on benchmark one based on completes: you create one set of bars by referencing d.benchmark (as you did) and then you do the same with d.completes.

Comment: Yes! That's my idea. However, I don't know how to put all of them in the same 'g' selection.

Comment: you just repeat the subcat.selectAll('.bar.trans') statement and have y and height attributes set based on completes. Then these bars are added to the g (which is referenced by subcat). All you need to do is making the second set of bars half transparent, e.g. by setting the opacity to 0.5 in your css block.